# How can I embed a htm file from a Wordpress directory using php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code that I want to include in my wordpress content and display an html file depending on the submitted values. What do I need to do to make this work? I'm new to wordpress so any help would be very much appreciated. I have already installed a plugin for php to work with my Wordpress site. Thank you in advance

```
                           <h3>Province:</h3>

                           <select name="province" >
                                 <option value="A" >A</option>
                                 <option value="B" >B</option>
                                 <option value="C" >C</option>
                                 <option value="D" >D</option>
                                 <option value="E" >E</option>
                           </select>

                            <h3>Year:</h3>

                            <?php
                            $years = array();
                            for ($i = 2018; $i > 2012; $i--)
                            {
                              $years[] = $i;
                            } 
                            echo "<select name='year'>";
                            foreach($years as $option){
                                echo "<option value='{$option}'>{$option}</option>";    
                            }
                            echo "</select>";
                            ?>

                            <h3>Month:</h3>
                            <select name="month" >
                                <option value="January" >January</option>
                                <option value="February" >February</option>
                                <option value="March" >March</option>
                                <option value="April" >April</option>
                                <option value="May" >May</option>
                                <option value="June" >June</option>
                                <option value="July" >July</option>
                                <option value="August" >August</option>
                                <option value="September" >September</option>
                                <option value="October" >October</option>
                                <option value="November" >November</option>
                                <option value="December" >December</option>

                            </select>

                            <div>
                             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                            <div >
                            <?php
                            if($_GET){
                               echo "<strong>".$_GET['province']." Price Monitoring as of ".$_GET['month']." ".$_GET['year']."</strong>"; }
                            ?>
                            </div>
                         </form>

            <div>
                /*access file directory using submitted fields */
                <?php
                if($_GET){
                   echo '<embed  src=wp-content/uploads/pricewatch/'.$_GET['province'].''.$_GET['month'].''.$_GET['year'].'.htm width="700" height="800"{ # code...}/>';

                }                    
                ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, it looks like you're relatively close, it mostly looks like your `<embed>` tag is messed up, thus not working.

Take a look at this link: https://xhynk.com/KrutSednar.php

Leave the `Year` value as 2018, as I've only create a `2018.htm`

If I were you, I would use <kbd>[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)</kbd> instead of `<embed>` - but either method (or even `<iframe>` would work to pull in your HTML file.

I've taken the liberty of cleaning up your code a bit, but the main piece to note is that you could replace your `<embed>` line with this:

```
if( $_GET ) echo file_get_contents( '/wp-content/uploads/pricewatch/$province/$month/$year.htm' );
```

Here's the updated code. A few notes:

- You didn't have a `<form>` in your example so I made this `action` the current URL.
- I simplified your `$year` loop
- I turned your `$months` into a similar loop.
- I personally like to loop through arrays (like `$_GET`) and turn `$_GET['year']` into `$year`, that's what the `$key => $val` loop is for.
- In my code at the bottom, you may need to update the path of the `.htm` files, I added slashes because I assumed they'd be there, but you can modify that string as needed.

Hope that makes sense!

```
<form action="<?= ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? "https" : "http" ) . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>">
    <div>
        <h3>Province:</h3>
        <select name="province">
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
            <option value="E">E</option>
        </select>

        <h3>Year:</h3>
        <select name="year">
            <?php for( $i = 2018; $i > 2012; --$i ) echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>"; ?>
        </select>

        <h3>Month:</h3>
        <select name="month">
            <?php for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; ++$m ){
                $month = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m, 1 ) );
                echo "<option value='$month'>$month</option>";
            } ?>
        </select>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
            if( $_GET ){
                foreach( $_GET as $key => $val ) ${$key} = $val;
                echo "<strong>$province Price Monitoring as of $month $year</strong>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    <?php
        if( $_GET ) echo file_get_contents( '/wp-content/uploads/pricewatch/$province/$month/$year.htm' );
        //if( $_GET ) echo "<embed src='/wp-content/uploads/pricewatch/$province/$month/$year.htm' width='700' height='800'";
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error. It says "SORRY, THE PAGE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR CANNOT BE FOUND
The page you requested may have been moved to a new location or removed from the site. 
Go back to the HOME PAGE or find what you are looking for in the search box below." but you helped me a lot in cleaning the codes. thank you for that!

Comment: I also tried to remove  <?php
        if( $_GET ) echo file_get_contents( '/wp-content/uploads/pricewatch/$province/$month/$year.htm' );
    ?> and same error pops up when i click submit

Comment: That error means your form is redirecting to the wrong place. Check your `<form action>`, not that your HTM file is missing. the `file_get_contents` will throw an error in the file inside that div that says `Warning: file_get_contents(FILENAME.htm): failed to open stream`

Comment: If you're using the `embed` option and you get that error, it means your embed `src` URL is wrong and needs to be updated to reflect the actual URL to the htm file.

Comment: i'm using file_get_contents. i checked the directory and everything is fine. I still don't know why the page isn't loading the .htm file.

Comment: `file_get_contents` doesn't throw that error. That confirms that you need to change your `<form action>` - it's redirecting to a page that doesn't exist. Try just `<form action="">`

Comment: Tweaked it a bit and here's my current error "Warning: file_get_contents(/wp-content/uploads/pricewatch/Cagayan/2017/January.htm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\php-everywhere\shortcode.php(15) : eval()'d code on line 40"

Comment: So now your form action is right, but the html file isn't. If the directory structures is right, try the following for the last line: `if( $_GET ) echo file_get_contents( content_url( "/uploads/pricewatch/$province/$month/$year.htm" ) );`

Comment: I tried using the url for the .htm file and i was able to show it properly on the content. Here's the problem, whenever I select a province or year or month and click submit, it says ""SORRY, THE PAGE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR CANNOT BE FOUND The page you requested may have been moved to a new location or removed from the site. Go back to the HOME PAGE or find what you are looking for in the search box below."

Comment: Oi, I thought you fixed that issue. Like I said, that issue means your `<form action="">` way at the top of the page is **incorrect** and needs to be updated. What's the URL of the current page, and what's the URL in your `<form action=`?

Comment: Current page is http://localhost/wordpress/price-watch/
then i used this <form action="<?= ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? "https" : "http" ) . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>">

Comment: You can probably just change it to `<form action="/wordpress/price-watch/">` or `<form action="<?= site_url( '/price-watch/' ); ?>">`

Comment: Tried both, and still the same error when I select any option then submit. do you know of any widget with the same function as to what I need? haha.

Comment: What is the URL after you submit?

Comment: Or do you have any funky characters in your `province`?

Comment: You could try using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` as well. Change your form to `<form method="post" action="<?= site_url( '/price-watch/' ); ?>">` and find and replace all the `$_GET` with `$_POST`

Comment: Error only occurs when i select an option before i clicked on submit.